# How can I update React state with child nodes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, nested

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
AppContext = {
  text: "some string",
  subText: {
    sub1: "sub string 1",
    sub2: "sub string 2"
  }
}
```

How would I dynamically set all values?

I'm trying with `onChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)`

`setValues({ ...values, [name]: value })`

The form is like:

```
<input name="text" value={values.text}` onChange... />
<input name="sub1" value={values.subText.sub1}` onChange... />
<input name="sub3" value={values.subText.sub2}` onChange... />
```

Am I naming the inputs right? Everytime the values is appended at the root node, not in the subText node.

Comment: What's with the backticks in your markup?

Comment: for subText - `setValues({ ...values, subText: { ...values.subText, [name]: value } }`

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) method of `lodash`.

> Sets the value at path of object

But we need to change the `name` props of the `<input/>` component to match the property path of the `values` state to avoid the property's name conflict.

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
        text: 'some string',
        subText: {
            sub1: 'sub string 1',
            sub2: 'sub string 2',
        },
    });

    const onInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const nextValues = _.chain(values).clone().set(e.target.name, e.target.value).value();
        console.log(nextValues);
        setValues(nextValues);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input name="text" value={values.text} onChange={onInputChange} />
            <input name="subText.sub1" value={values.subText.sub1} onChange={onInputChange} />
            <input name="subText.sub2" value={values.subText.sub2} onChange={onInputChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76672517-k5zrcr?file=/src/App.tsx)